# Using CodeIgniter to populate drop down lists in forms

Tags: php, codeigniter

Being new to CI and PHP, especially arrays, I'm struggling with documentation and tutorials. Please don't point me to the documentation, I have been reading it all day.

As I understand it, I need a view (form), controller and model. The model connects to my default DB connection via a class/function (my DB is where my drop-down list country data is stored), it returns an array, and finally the model parses the array to the form.

Where I struggle is how to parse the array along to the view. Because I'm dealing with 3 files, to output one html file, context is really important, as is syntax. I asked this earlier today and nearly lost my mind as the two answers I got were fragmented and out of context. They were helpful but assumed I knew a lot more than I do.

In other words, please be explicit, because a syntax oversight or knowledge assumption could have me scratching my head for hours. Thanks in advance!

Here's my attempt which isn't working, basically whatever variable I use in the view returns a variable undefined error...

View/Form...

```
<body>   
<?php echo form_open('form'); ?> 

<h5>Country</h5>
<?php echo form_dropdown('', $data, '');?>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>    
<?php echo form_close() ?>    
</body>
```

My controller...

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        




        $this->load->model('country');
        $data['country'] = $this->country->get_country();
        $this->load->view('myform', $data);


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->database();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO donations (country) VALUES (
            ".$this->db->escape($this->input->post('country')).";

            $this->db->query($sql);

            echo $this->db->affected_rows(); 

            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My model...

```
<?php

class Country extends CI_Model
{

function get_country() {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = ('select * from countries');
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

You have `$data['country']` with data from database, but your are not adding the $data to the view.
Use `$this->load->view('myform', $data);` to pass the data to the view.

**View**

I believe codeigniter extracts the key in the `$data`:
so simply test in the view what's there `var_dump($data);` and `var_dump($country)` and
then build the form_dropdown.

Use `echo form_dropdown('country_dropdown', $country, '');` in your view.

**Model**

Adjust the model to return the array structure needed for form_dropdown.

```
function get_country() {
  $this->load->database();
  $sql = ('select * from countries');
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);

  foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $data[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
  }

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: OK I added that line to my controller, so the relevant part now says... `$this->load->model('country');
        $data['country'] = $this->country->get_country();
 $this->load->view('myform', $data);'
However I still get the error unknown variable $data. Also what do you mean "If country is set'?

Comment: Test if $country is set by var_dump($country); inside the view. If the var_dump displays something, you have your data and can build the dropdown.

Comment: It produces what looks like a full array output of my country data, but also a PHP error `Message: Undefined variable: data Filename: views/myform.php`

Comment: If I use $country for the array I get 200 odd errors `Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php`

Comment: Ok, now you know: $data is not available. The keys from $data are extracted - and now available as vars in the view. Do not use $data in the view to get rid of that error. $country is available. Now: you need to adjust the array structure of $country so that form_dropdown can understand it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49440/discussion-between-square-eyes-and-jens-andre-koch)